# change size of Preview image before it is uploaded

Tags: javascript, image, file-upload, image-resizing, preview

How Can I change the size of the preview image to width = 100 and height= 100

```
function imagePreviewFunc(that, previewerId) {
 let files = that.files
    previewerId.innerHTML='' // reset image preview element

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let imager = document.createElement("img");
   
        imager.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
        previewerId.append(imager);
    }
 }
<label for="image1">Imagen 1</label>
<input class="form-control" accept="image/*" name ="image1" type='file' id="imageInput_1" 
  onchange="imagePreviewFunc(this, imagePreview_1)" />
 <div id="imagePreview_1"></div> // preview size too large
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a basic CSS question.
Simply set the image size using CSS:

```css
#imagePreview_1 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;   /* or use: contain */
}
```

or directly from JS:

```js
imager.style.cssText = `width: 100px; height: 100px; object-fit: cover;`
```